# Formula regarding percantage

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula for the below.

If answer (tab) is greater than 485.74 than the answer will be 48.57
If answer (tab) is less than 485.74 than the answer will be multiplied by 10%

```
=(AND(C4>485.74)*"48.57"+OR(C4<485.74)*10%)
```

this is the formula I wrote

The problem is that is calculating the percentage wrong

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can use:

```
=MIN(48.57,C4*10%)
```